# How can I get only specific object from nested array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, filter, aggregation-framework

I'm using mongoDB with PHP. I know how to get the document based on `product_id`, but I need only a specific object from the whole document, I don't know how to get only specific object from nested array based on `product_id`.

for ex. My expected output is:

```
products": [
  {
    "product_id": 547,
    "name": "cola",
    "quantity": 24
  }
]
```

then make some changes on object p.s update the `quantity` then update it to the database.

My collection looks like

```
"_id": {
 "$oid": "62ed30855836b16fd38a00b9"
},
"name": "drink",
"products": [
 {
   "product_id": 547,
   "name": "cola",
   "quantity": 24
 },
 {
   "product_id": 984,
   "name": "fanta",
   "quantity": 42
 },
 {
   "product_id": 404,
   "name": "sprite",
   "quantity": 12
 },
 {
   "product_id": 854,
   "name": "water",
   "quantity": 35
 }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$products"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "products.product_id": 547
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$ROOT",
                    "$products"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "products": 0
        }
    }
])
```

The query gives the following output:

```
{
    "name" : "cola",
    "product_id" : 547,
    "quantity" : 24
}
```

Comment: works perfect. Can you help me how can I update on this same way p.s update quantity of product and update only this object

Comment: You need to add $set as the last stage of your aggregate.

Comment: I'm trying to update with same query but the last stage as 

`'$set' => ['products' => $to_update_array]`

but doesn't work, can you correct me ? @sudhanva